# Way to confirm if data has been rendered

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, frontend, cypress

Is there a way to confirm that all the data requested via web socket API has been rendered in a page? I have tried the below:

```
cy.visit('https://something.qa.com/customer_orders/all?page[num]=1&page[size]=100')
cy.get(collection_details).should('contain','some text')
```

But cy.visit() sometimes returns before the data is rendered and proceeds to the next step, which errors out.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"does not work consistently"*?

Comment: cy.visit() does not waits until the data is rendered many times. And when it moves to the next statement cy.get(collection_details), it cannot find collection_details and error out.

Comment: Have you tried [configuring the timeouts](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Timeouts)? What information does cypress give you about what's happened? Please [edit] the question.

Comment: Configuring timeout for cy.visit() works ! Thank you. But would like to know if there a way to confirm if the data rendering using a web socket API exists.

Comment: Your current code *is* the way you check if that data is getting rendered. That's why it sometimes passes. Cypress doesn't care whether it's in the original HTML, loaded via AJAX or received from a websocket. It's unclear what else you want to know.

Comment: Now I have given the timeout to be 3 secs and if the data for some reason (maybe the web socket conx is lost) is not rendered within that time and proceeds to next cy.get() steps, the code will error out. I can increase the timeout again.